# Need to add counter column that is partitioned by like row entries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, myspace

First off, thanks to everyone that has attempted to help with my questions. It's greatly appreciated.

I have the following statement to pull the selected data and give SUM and AVG for Inp/Outp Amount & Count. Now that I have the data I need, I need to eliminate the issue that is causing extra rows for entries with the same ProcedureID, as the output is the same since it is partitioned based on ProcedureID. The idea I had was to add a counter column to the statement that is also partitioned to count by ProcedureID. Then SELECT the Highest or Lowest integer into a temptable and I'd be done.

```
SELECT  M.ProcedureID,
        M.SegmentDateTime,
    M.PriceID,
    L.DrugID,
    L.NdcDinNumber,
    L.Name,
    M.DeptCorporation,
    M.InpAmount,
    M.InpCount,
    M.OutAmount,
    M.OutCount,

       SUM(InpCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as INtotal,
       SUM(InpAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as  IN$Total,
       SUM(OutCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as OUTtotal,
       SUM(OutAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as  OUT$Total,
       SUM(InpCount + OutCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as TotalCount,
       SUM(InpAmount + OutAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as TotalAmount
       AVG(InpCount + OutCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as AverageCount,
       AVG(InpAmount + OutAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as AverageAmount

        FROM BarRevenueByProcedurePriceInfo M

LEFT JOIN DPhaDrugData L ON 
M.ProcedureID = L.BillNumber


    WHERE DeptID = '010.4730'
AND SegmentDateTime = '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000'
AND M.InpCount > '0'

OR

 DeptID = '010.4730'
AND SegmentDateTime = '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000'
AND M.OutCount > '0'

    ORDER BY ProcedureID
```

Since I'm still fairly new to SQL I figured I'd ask the experts. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do it with CTE: Add a column containing the `Row_number() over (partition by ProcedureID order by ProcedureID) as seq` in your current query and then `select * from CTE where seq=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three possible methods to do what you want to do.

Here is a `row_number()` method:

```
with p as (
    SELECT M.ProcedureID, M.SegmentDateTime, M.PriceID,
           L.DrugID, L.NdcDinNumber, L.Name, M.DeptCorporation, M.InpAmount,
           M.InpCount, M.OutAmount, M.OutCount,
           row_number() over (partition by procedureID order by (select NULL)) as seqnum,
           SUM(InpCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as INtotal,
           SUM(InpAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as  IN$Total,
           SUM(OutCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as OUTtotal,
           SUM(OutAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as  OUT$Total,
           SUM(InpCount + OutCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as TotalCount,
           SUM(InpAmount + OutAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as TotalAmount
           AVG(InpCount + OutCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as AverageCount,
           AVG(InpAmount + OutAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as AverageAmount
    FROM BarRevenueByProcedurePriceInfo M LEFT JOIN
         DPhaDrugData L
         ON M.ProcedureID = L.BillNumber
    WHERE DeptID = '010.4730' AND SegmentDateTime = '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND
          (M.InpCount > '0' or M.OutCount > '0')
   )
select p.*
from p
where seqnum = 1
ORDER BY ProcedureID;
```

You might want to remove `seqnum` from the list of removed columns.

Another method you can use is to just add `distinct` after the `select`.

Finally, I suspect your query is equivalent to:

```
    SELECT M.ProcedureID, M.SegmentDateTime, M.PriceID,
           L.DrugID, L.NdcDinNumber, L.Name, M.DeptCorporation, M.InpAmount,
           M.InpCount, M.OutAmount, M.OutCount,
           SUM(InpCount) as INtotal,
           SUM(InpAmount) as  IN$Total,
           SUM(OutCount) as OUTtotal,
           SUM(OutAmount) as  OUT$Total,
           SUM(InpCount + OutCount) as TotalCount,
           SUM(InpAmount + OutAmount) as TotalAmount
           AVG(InpCount + OutCount) as AverageCount,
           AVG(InpAmount + OutAmount) as AverageAmount
    FROM BarRevenueByProcedurePriceInfo M LEFT JOIN
         DPhaDrugData L
         ON M.ProcedureID = L.BillNumber
    WHERE DeptID = '010.4730' AND SegmentDateTime = '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND
          (M.InpCount > '0' or M.OutCount > '0')
    GROUP BY M.ProcedureID, M.SegmentDateTime, M.PriceID,
             L.DrugID, L.NdcDinNumber, L.Name, M.DeptCorporation, M.InpAmount,
             M.InpCount, M.OutAmount, M.OutCount;
```

Comment: I tried adding DISTINCT. Since the row entries contain different data in some columns it doesn't give me the one record for each that I need. I added the row_number () over (partition by ProcedureID order by (select NULL)) as seqnum and got the counter column. Now I just need to drop the highest integer for each ProcedureID into a temptable and I'm done.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Used a variation of the two suggestions. That worked perfectly using CTE.

Comment: @YepItsMe . . . I wrote out the whole query and left outer the critical piece . . . `where seqnum = 1`.

Comment: No worries, I'm new to SQL but I could figure that out. Thanks sooo much